# When would one use jQuery isImmediatePropagationStopped() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

In what situation would one use jQuery's [isImmediatePropagationStopped](http://api.jquery.com/event.isImmediatePropagationStopped/) method? Example on their documentation page does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were in a situation with multiple [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) events for example, you'd want to [`.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) then check it in a following handler, since you've already bubbled up to the same element.  Let's take a live example:

```
$("a").live("click", function(e) {
    alert("Handler 1");
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}).live("click", function(e) {
    alert("Handler 2");
});
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/jGJRY/1/) - notice both alerts still fire.

Even though we're stopping propagation immediately, we're listening at a level it doesn't matter, so we actually need to check it:

```
$("a").live("click", function(e) {
    alert("Handler 1");
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}).live("click", function(e) {
    if(e.isPropagationStopped()) return;
    alert("Handler 2");
});
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/jGJRY/2/) - only the first alert fires, the desired result.  Depending on your event order, the same situation happens with [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).  There are other examples of course, but these are the situations you're at all likely to encounter in normal usage.

Comment: I see. I actually have only one .live() event handler on a control.  However, the control is on page twice, hence handler gets called twice. Setting and checking ImmediatePropagation in handler works but I feel that a better solution would be if the event was getting called once for control that initiated that event.

Comment: With jquery 1.8 the first example only fire one event the the stop propagation prevent the other one